# why data-inputmask is not working : npmjs

Tags: javascript, input-mask, jquery-inputmask

I am trying to apply phone number masking. I followed this [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inputmask) and did everything but still, phone masking is not working.

[image]

Below is the code.

```html
var template = '\
<div class="contactItem">\
                    <label style="padding:6px" >Home phone</label>\
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-inputmask="\'mask\': \'999-99-9999\'" /> \
                    </div>\
                </div>\
';

self.dialog = puDialogV2.showDialog($('.body-content'), 'Add Contact', template, self, self.addContact, self.cancelSaveContact);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are following the "via data-inputmask attribute" option in documentation. Most probably you are missing the second part of it. Try adding below code to your javascript part.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // $(":input").inputmask();
  // or
  Inputmask().mask(document.querySelectorAll("input"));
});
```